# Magento ver. 2.1.7 coupon code not working checkout page

Tags: magento2

Hello I am using cart price rule. When I try to apply coupon code into cart page at that time in cart page successfully apply coupon code, but in checkout page coupon code is not apply, or I applied coupon code from cart page then I can not remove coupon code from checkout page.

I am getting the following error when I am trying to apply or cancel coupon code:

```
 jquery.js:10254 DELETE https://domain.nl/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/coupons 404 () send @ jquery.js:10254 ajax @ jquery.js:9738 delete @ storage.js:78 (anonymous) @ cancel-coupon.js:35 cancel @ discount.js:51 (anonymous) @ knockout.js:3863 dispatch @ jquery.js:5226 elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4878 VM19906:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.process (error-processor.js:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (cancel-coupon.js:56)
    at fire (jquery.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3362)
    at done (jquery.js:9842)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10311) process @ error-processor.js:19 (anonymous) @ cancel-coupon.js:56 fire @ jquery.js:3232 fireWith @ jquery.js:3362 done @ jquery.js:9842 callback @ jquery.js:10311 XMLHttpRequest.send (async) send @ jquery.js:10254 ajax @ jquery.js:9738 delete @ storage.js:78 (anonymous) @ cancel-coupon.js:35 cancel @ discount.js:51 (anonymous) @ knockout.js:3863 dispatch @ jquery.js:5226 elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4878 jquery.js:10254 XHR failed loading: DELETE "https://domain.nl/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/coupons".
```

=> I am also using amasty one step checkout plugin, but I have checked after disable "Amasty OSC" but coupon code not working in checkout page.

Thanks,
Dhvanit

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to the server settings. You server doesn't accept PUT requests. 
It means that all Magento's parts which perform PUT requests to the server, will show errors. 
Please contact with your server provider.
And not apply cancel coupon code then enable DELETE requests.